# If I want a faster camera preview FPS, will I have to use the NDK?

Tags: java, android, sdk, camera

I'm trying to get the preview frame rate up, but setPreviewFrameRate isn't supported on my phone.  The max I can get using setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer and with no extra processing is about 17 fps, which I think most people would agree is kind of crappy.  Am I missing something in the Android Java SDK or will I need to learn about the NDK to handle data at a full 30 fps? (I should point out that the camera can capture and save files at this rate -- apparently it just can't preview at this rate).

Are there any disadvantages of using the NDK that I should know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been in this situation, and reading from the camera was faster in the NDK. However, I rooted the phone and read straight from the framebuffer, and it probably wasn't the same phone you're developing for, so YMMV.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to make an app actually.  Is reading the framebuffer directly not supported without rooting?